# Print out a char in main method

Tags: haskell

I have two modules defined as follows:

Foo.hs

```
module Foo
where

class F t where
  c :: t -> Char

instance F Double where
  c s = 'x'
```

Main.hs

```
import Foo

main :: IO ()
main =  do
  print $ (c 2.0)
```

When I compile these two modules I get this error:

```
ghc Foo.hs Main.hs 
[1 of 2] Compiling Foo              ( Foo.hs, Foo.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( Main.hs, Main.o )

Main.hs:6:12: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘c’
      prevents the constraint ‘(F t0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instance exist:
        instance [safe] F Double -- Defined in ‘Foo’
    • In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘(c 2.0)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ (c 2.0)
      In the expression: do { print $ (c 2.0) }

Main.hs:6:14: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from the literal ‘2.0’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Fractional t0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Fractional Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Fractional Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus one instance involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘c’, namely ‘2.0’
      In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely ‘(c 2.0)’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block: print $ (c 2.0)
```

How do I fix this so it prints out 'x'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just rename `call` to `c`.

EDIT: Try annotating `2.0` as `Double`:

```
print $ c (2.0 :: Double)
```

GHC doesn't know which type to use for `2.0`, it could be any `Fractional` type. To fix this we force `2.0` to be of type `Double` by explicitly marking its type.

Comment: ...which is what GHC was suggesting in "Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be."

Comment: @chi Yes it does, but GHC's error messages seem a bit cryptic at the beginning, at least IMO.